# What does み mean? とうさんのうえたニンジンはたくさんのみをつけた

Tags: meaning, words

I'm reading children's books in Japanese to study Japanese, but since they are for children, it's all in hiragana. In one part there is とうさんのうえたニンジンはたくさんのみをつけた, but there are many meanings to み. What does it mean in this case?

Comment: https://jisho.org/search/%E5%AE%9F%E3%82%92%E4%BB%98%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B

Comment: `ニンジンはたくさんのみをつけた` -- ニンジンの実っていうと、[こんなの](https://scontent-itm1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t39.30808-6/299130801_5329378703836636_4128042617116902161_n.jpg?_nc_cat=107&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=730e14&_nc_ohc=O7xh9qc7aBgAX-w4VMJ&_nc_ht=scontent-itm1-1.xx&oh=00_AT_CzRuVu2RiS_8K44t2g8FkYrUxd53hpWqe7Zcu1kc_hw&oe=62FD637C)ですね。。 ニンジンは根っこを食べるので

Answer (score 5):

This み is 実 in kanji, and it means 'fruit' in the biological sense. 実【み】を付ける【つける】 is a set phrase meaning 'to bear fruit'.

As Chocolate pointed out, technically speaking, the 実 of the carrot is something like [this](https://hananusubito.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-10143.html). The orange part we eat is technically 根 (root). Since this is a children's book, let's just overlook this small mistake and understand that it means many (orange) carrots were produced.